# What are the benefits of a fad diet?

Tags: nutrition, diet, weight, weight-loss, fad-diet

I have researched and found that fad diets are harmful and are only short-term but it cant just 100% negative.

I mean what if I am 200 kg and cant enter an event because of the weight limit of 100kg. If I am able to find a diet/exercise plan to reduce 100kg in some amount of time, then why not?

I mean the body will try and push you back to that weight because it is not used to being at a different weight but if a person can control themselves then there should be no problem. Soon the body will start to accept your new weight and then you do not have to miss out.

This is my reasoning.

Comment: Did you really mean the numbers you used as an example? Losing 100 kg would take years on any sane diet. Perhaps you meant 10 kg?

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29885/can-weight-lost-be-sustained-through-exercise-influenced-metabolism-changes

Comment: @CareyGregory with sufficient amount of exercise to help.

Comment: Do the math. 100 kg is 8.3 kg per month, which might be possible the first few months for someone starting out at 200 kg, but continuing that rate of weight loss for 12 months would be an astonishing feat. There is no diet that will achieve that without being very unhealthy and probably dangerous.